# VBA Grid Generation with User Input

Tags: excel, vba, grid

The aim of this code is to have the user input that they want an, e.g. 4x10 grid. I have attached a photo below of the desired output.

However, I'm stuck on the logic of the problem. I can generate one set of grid numbers (e.g. 1-25), but unsure how to duplicate this process to create the whole grid.

Hard to explain using words....

In short I am aiming for:

A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4 ...

But I am currently getting: A1, B2, C3, D4 ...

Tried experimenting with different code but to no success. Current code has a loop that I think is right in principle, but re-writes the data in the rows above it once it finishes one 'j' loop and goes back to the start. I'm not sure how to get 'j' to start on a blank cell rather than overwrite what is already in it.

```
['Userform prior to this step gathers user input 

Dim Axial_Data_Points As Variant
Dim Circum_Data_Points As Variant    

Axial_Data_Points = Axial_Data_Points_Box.Value    'User input value
Circum_Data_Points = Circum_Data_Points_Box.Value  'User input value

'Basic loop to generate a list of numbers up to the user imposed limit
For j = 1 To Axial_Data_Points
    Worksheets("Data Entry").Activate
    For k = 1 To Circum_Data_Points
        Range("E" & ((j + k) + 1)).Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = j
    Next k
Next j]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR27c.png)

Comment: No photo Attached!

Comment: It won't let me embed a photo, but said it was attached.. will try again

Comment: See if you want it look something like in the Answer.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rR27c.png

This is the link it gives me if this works...

Comment: So you will enter 4 as Axial Data Points & 10 as the other ?

Comment: Up to the user. The user input box allows them to put any value the Circum / Axial boxes, that then defines how big the grid should be.

Comment: See the Answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will produce output like:

```
Dim Axial_Data_Points As Variant
Dim Circum_Data_Points As Variant


    Axial_Data_Points = Axial_Data_Points_Box.Value     'User input value
    Circum_Data_Points = Circum_Data_Points_Box.Value   'User input value


'Basic loop to generate a list of numbers up to the user imposed limit

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer


For i = 1 To Axial_Data_Points

    For j = 1 To Circum_Data_Points

       Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + (i - 1) * 10, 4).Value = Chr(i + 64)
       Worksheets("Data Entry").Cells(j + (i - 1) * 10, 5).Value = j

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

[image]

---

Using Something of this type you can generate what you require:

```
j = 1
k = 1

For i = 1 To 200

    If j < 27 Then

        Range("A" & i).Value = Chr(j + 64)
        j = j + 1

    ElseIf j > 26 And j < 53 Then
G:
        Range("A" & i).Value = Chr(k + 64) & Chr(j - 26 + 64)
        j = j + 1

    Else

        j = 27
        k = k + 1
        GoTo G

    End If

Next
```

You will have to put it in your code.

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly. I would add that instead of ' 10 ', making it the 'Circum_Data_Points_Box" value, as this ensures there are no blank cells between the loops.

Comment: Correct ... Happy to help :)

Comment: Mikku, sorry but just to add on to the above... with Chr turning numbers into letter references, how do you set it up to give 'AA' instead of a symbol once the numbers exceed 100? (i.e. achieve X, Y, Z, AA, BB, CC, DD....)

Comment: Actually it will print Alphabets up to the the Number 26. After that you will start seeing Symbols. To go around that problem, you would want to divide your `Axial_Data_Points` with 26 and run the Loop according to the answer of that division.